# profile doesn't match valid certificate

Tags: iphone, profile

What my problem is:

I have installed distribution certificate. And it's installed successfully. In my Keychain, it's displaying with key/pair properly.

Then, I have installed the AdHoc profile in my xcode. And it's also installed successfully.

But my issue is that, when I am opening the Xcode 3.2.6 and select the AdHoc profile from my project, it's working properly.

Now, I am open the same project in Xcode 4.2 and try to bind the profile but it says "profile doesn't match valid certificate". So I am not able to select the AdHoc profile.

What can be problem?
Because profile is working successfully in Xcode 3.2.6 while in Xcode 4.2 it's not installed.

Has anyone faced the problem before?

Looking for your help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having both Xcode versions in the same machine?

Comment: Having multiple Xcode on same machine wont make any difference, since I have running both Xcode 3.2 & 4 in system.It's something, you can try to again by deleting the Provisional Profile from Organizer of Xcode4.

Comment: Yes, I am using both Xcode 3.2.6 and 4.2 in same Mac. I have tried with deleting certificate and profile. And then re-install. But same error in Xcode 4. Strange thing is that, when I am opening the project in Xcode 3.2.6 then profile is binding with certificate properly. I have seen it in Organizer. But when I am opening the same project in Xcode 4.2 then profile is not binding with given certificate. And it gives the error as "Valid Signing identity not found". Is it related to that, other person has not properly exported the certificate in .p12 format?